# How can I make sure a new ec2_eip is ready for the next task?

Tags: ansible

When using [ec2_eip](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_eip_module.html) to associate or disassociate an ElasticIP, it takes a few seconds for the new IP to become available. But `wait_for` often fails with a fatal error `SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh`. How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait_for` does many things- it can watch for a file, or it can watch for a port. In your case, you aren't watching for a web server to finish starting/stopping, you are wanting to know that a server has come up.

There's some hidden nuance in here- commands are run on *remote* nodes, so the `SSH Error` isn't from inside `wait_for`, it's from Ansible itself, as Ansible is trying to connect and run `wait_for` remotely.

What does this mean? You need to run `wait_for` on the server side and wait for the node to come alive.

```
- name: wait for server to finish booting
  local_action: wait_for port=22 timeout=60 host="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

This can be seen in the final example on the [`wait_for` documentation page](http://docs.ansible.com/wait_for_module.html). Still, it's only implied, so it's easy to miss.

Comment: Good point, and `wait_for` has several `port` examples but only one specifies local. Is there a difference here between `local_action` and `connection: local`? Or `delegate_to: localhost`?

Comment: `delegate_to` would work, but `connection: local` is for entire playbooks.

Answer (score 1):

In my testing with elastic IPs, this seems to work well:

```
- pause: seconds=15
- name: wait for ssh
  wait_for: port=22 timeout=600
```

This feels like a hack, but [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_eip_module.html) says "Use wait_for and pause to delay further playbook execution until the instance is reachable, if necessary." So it's an official hack.

You could experiment with the pause length, especially if you still see errors after 15 seconds. I found that `seconds=5` or `seconds=10` was not long enough.